# Keycodes for meta keys[backspace][ctrl][alt] with upper and lower case letters

Tags: javascript, html, keypress

How to get keycode on keypress?

I know that keydown and keyup will give keycodes for all keys but without considering the case for alphabets 
and also keypress will give case sensitive keycodes but donot give keycodes for meta keys like  <kbd>backspace</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>. is there any method to get all the keycodes including meta and case sensitive keycodes? in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around for this problem.

Events execute in this order

1, Key down
2, key press
3, key up

Steps to solve problem

1, use two events, key down and key press
2, cancel event in keydown if keycode is in range of capital letters
3, execute event in key up

```
var cancelKeypress = false;
$("body").keydown(function(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    var eliminateKeys = [];
    for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) { //Capital Letters [A-Z]
        eliminateKeys.push(i);
    }
    eliminateKeys.push(32); // space
    cancelKeypress = eliminateKeys.indexOf(event.keyCode) == -1 ? false : true;
    if (cancelKeypress) {
        //return false;
    }
    else{
        Main.processTrigger(event);// your processtrigger function
    }
}); 
$("body").keypress(function(event){
    if (cancelKeypress) {
        Main.processTrigger(event); // your processtrigger function
        console.log(event);
    }
    else{
        //return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not use the `event.shiftKey` flag instead?

Comment: I doubt this would solve the problem. Have you tested it on all browsers? Mozilla FF on `keypress` also includes keycodes for Ctrl & function keys, and even though MDN says the '`e.keyCode || charCode`' props are deprecated, it still has them. In all browsers but Mozilla your `keypress` event will not be triggered for what you called 'meta' keys.

Comment: @Tyblitz : My whole idea is to eliminate alphabets and special symbols in keydown event.
1. all alphabets and special chars  -> handle in keypress
2. Meta keys like [bksp]  -> Handle in keydown